# Duvida com ponteiros em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária

Ola, estou procurando a hrs o problema neste trecho (implementação de uma arvore avl) mas não consigo encontrar, eu passso um Dicionario D para esta função e o seu valor é modificado dentro do contexto, mas não é modificado no contexto em que a função é chamada.

Dicionario.c

```
struct No * RotacionaEsquerda(struct No * Pai)
{
printf("Rotacionando %d para a esquerda\n", GetChave(Pai->I));

struct No * Filho = Pai->direita;
Pai->direita = Filho->esquerda;
Filho->esquerda = Pai;
return Filho;
}

void Balanceamento (struct Dicionario * D, struct No * Pai) {

int Fator = FatorDeBalanceamento (Pai);

if (Fator >= 2) {
// Arvore tendendo a direita
        Pai = RotacionaEsquerda(Pai);
        // Raiz é modificado neste contesto
        D->raiz;
} else {
    if (Fator <= -2) {
    //Arvore tendendo a esquerda

    }
}
```

Cliente.c

```
int main()
{
srand( time(NULL) );

struct Dicionario * D = CriaDicionario();
int totalNiveis = 0;    

while(1)
{
    char comando[20];
    if(scanf("%s", comando) < 1 || strcmp(comando, "SAIR") == 0)
        break;  

    if(strcmp(comando, "INSERIR") == 0)
    {
        struct Item I;
        Chave c;
        scanf("%d", &c);
        SetChave(&I, c);

        Inserir(D, I);
    }
    else if(strcmp(comando, "BUSCAR") == 0)
    {
        Chave c;
        scanf("%d", &c);

        int niveis = Buscar(D, c);
        printf("%d\n", niveis);
        totalNiveis += niveis;
    }
    else if(strcmp(comando, "REMOVER") == 0)
    {
        Chave c;
        scanf("%d", &c);

        Remover(D, c);
    }
    else if(strcmp(comando, "IMPRIMIR") == 0)
    {
        Imprime(D);
    }
}
printf("%d\n", totalNiveis);
return 0;
}
```

Ao imprimir o Dicinario D no contexto da função Balanceamento exibe o output correto, mas ao tentar exibir no contexto da função main em Cliente.c ele exibe o antigo Dicionario D sem a esquerda e direita (Rotacionar a esquerda funcionando)

source code 
https://github.com/viniciusilidio/AED-II-TP-1

Comment: Vinicius, seu código está bem incompleto. Por favor, disponha-o de forma que seja possível compilar para que possamos testar e te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: Ok, adcionei o link do github

Comment: Sempre disponibilize o código completo na página, para que os usuários do futuro possam aproveitar da sua dúvida.